# How to configure wacom devices manually

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

In ubuntu 11.10 with xorg-1:7.6+7ubuntu7 and xserver-xorg-input-wacom 1:0.11.0-0ubuntu2

I've put in xorg.conf:

```
Section "InputDevice"
  Driver        "wacom"
  Identifier    "pen" # "eraser"|"finger"|"pad"
  Option        "Device"        "/dev/input/wacom"
  Option        "Type"          "stylus" # "eraser"|"touch"|"pad"
  Option        "Floating" "on"  
  Option        "Mode" "Absolute"
  Option        "Rotate" "NONE"
EndSection
```

Also i've disbaled "evdev tablet catchall" in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
to prevent creating alot of mice.

The Option "Floating" works well:

```
$ xinput --list
∼ pen                                       id=6    [floating slave]
∼ eraser                                    id=7    [floating slave]
∼ finger                                    id=8    [floating slave]
∼ pad                                       id=9    [floating slave]
```

However, all wacom-related options are ignored:

```
$ xsetwacom get pen all
Option "Mode" "Relative"
Option "Rotate" "half"
```

I have to run xsetwacom manually.

Comment: You've got alot further than I. I'm trying to setup a serial wacom Intous3 in 12.04. - Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: @palhmbs - You need to ask a question yourself so as not to confuse this one. As it is, wacom serial without pnp is dead and won't be coming back.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen settings in xorg.conf affect the xsetwacom and even the linux-wacom project's website has tutorials for putting xsetwacom commands into xinitrc:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/index_old.php/howto/xsetwacom

But, I see no reason why these settings shouldn't be set plug-and-play with the udev system. We just need a developer to write it up.